# Make git pull before push

Tags: git, git-merge

I have started working on my own feature branch, and I did multiple commits, then I want to switch to master branch and merge my commits from my feature branch, after I want to push the local master branch to remote branch. But before to switch to master branch, I did 'git pull' and it downloaded bunch of commits done in master branch by other guys, and when I want to merge my commits to local master branch it fails because git says that I have pending merges in my current feature branch, and I have to solve them before to merge.

Note: Nobody else is modifying the file I have changed in my feature branch.

Was it caused because I did 'git pull' before to switch to master branch? Or what would be the correct way or steps in order to avoid these weird things?

I have followed below steps:

```
$ git pull

$ echo 'line 1' > test.txt
$ git commit -a -m "commit 1"

$ echo 'line 2' > test.txt
$ git commit -a -m "commit 2"

$ echo 'line 3' > test.txt
$ git commit -a -m "commit 3"

$ git pull # Here was downloaded a lot of commits from master branch.

$ git merge my_feature_branch # Fails, because there are merge pending in my current feature branch.
```

Comment: https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-pull
pull is shorthand for git fetch followed by git merge FETCH_HEAD.

This means that you are in the middle of a merge (Check if there are conflicts)

Comment: Agreed. Run `git status` to see the details.

Comment: Avoid using `git pull` or `git push`, but use the explicit command like `git pull origin master`, `git push origin master:master`. In your case, use `git pull --rebase origin master` instead which makes your feature branch more tidy and clean. Personally I prefer a fast-forward merge whenever. Considering git pull may cause conflict, use `git stash` before it. If anything unexpected happens and your work tree becomes a mess, you could just `git stash pop` to restore.